# Partial matching with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pattern-matching, match

I have the following records

Master String

```
abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno
```

Records

```
abc,ghi,xyz
bbb,jkl
abc,ghi,mno
bbb,ggg
```

Each of these records are concatenated fields from another query. (the first record is a concatenation of "abc", "ghi" and "xyz").

From the above, I'm supposed to confirm if the fields in the strings contain a match to the master string.  In this scenario, the first three records are matching because they each have at least one field that matches the master string.

Is there any way to use a single query to handle this? The only way I can think off is to break each records into its components and matching it individually, but I am hoping for a more efficient solution. I can't seem to get regex to work with this either.

Comment: The result set is provided as such - and I can't do anything about the source data sorry to say....

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-atomize the `master` string. Fortunately you won't need to touch the `record` records.

This solution deploys regex to split the master string into tokens. These are cross-joined to the tokens. We use `instr()` to see whether the token exists in a record's string, and the result is aggregated to produce one record with a Y/N flag per `record`.

```
with m as ( 
    select regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+', 1, level) as tkn
    from master_t
    connect by level <= regexp_count(str, ',')+1
)
select r.str
       , max(case when instr(r.str, m.tkn) > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end) as in_str
from m
     cross join record_t r
group by r.str
/
```

---

Obviously this solution assumes you're dealing with tables. The question is a bit vague regarding your data structures. I hope you'll be able to apply this answer to your situation, but if you need further assistance please **edit your question** to provide clarification.